# How to add two columns in the listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, xamarin.android

How to add two columns in the listview and get the value of the first column.

I have Adapter that receives the data from a select and this data is added in the listview.

I would like the listview to be two columns and whenever I click on a row it takes the value of the first column

My listview is being populated like this:

```
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, observacao);
            lv.Adapter = adapter;
            lv.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
```

Comment: Create a Custom adapter and inflate a layout that splits the row in two. Inside ```onBindViewHolder```, add a click listener in each column of the adapter and delegate the event to whomever must process it.

Comment: @humble Student,Do you have an example to pass me?

Comment: Look for ListView custom adapter and use any layout (Linear or Relative) for doing the columns. Don have any example ready and this is a very basic subject, it is extremely easy to find examples of that on the web

Comment: In xamarin android? Well, I'm going to research and I'll give you a return. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: you should use RecycleView and set Recycleview as GridView by creating GridLayoutManger reference.

Answer (score 1):

you should use RecycleView and set Recycleview as GridView by creating GridLayoutManger reference and also you can specify column number in it.

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2));
            adapter = new FoodAdapter( context,filteredList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Need to create grid in xml? Will RecyclerView replace the listview? Is the context, filteredList, the data that comes from the database? And to get the clicked item is the same as the Position of the listview?

Comment: no you don't need to create grid XML because it will done by grid layout manager , you just make row item XML as you create for single entity and grid layout manger creates grid at run time and you can specify the no of column and it will be adjusted by screen size and you need to create recycle view adapter.

Comment: it is better to use one row item rather than using two row layout and managing position, recycleview simply can be used. if you done it in ListView it creates rough scrolling problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is official document about [Creating Custom Row Layouts](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/#Creating_Custom_Row_Layouts) for Xamarin Android.

Please follow that official tutorial to create a custom layout for the item of `ListView` and use your custom adapter for it.

In the `GetView` method of your custom adapter, you can inflate your row layout:

```
View view = convertView;
if (view == null)
    view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.YourCustomLayout, null);
```

> I would like the listview to be two columns and whenever I click on a row it takes the value of the first column

In the `ItemClick` event of your `ListView`, you can get the position of the selected item:

```
private void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.Position;
}
```

The position can be used for matching the relative item of your `List`, which is added into the `ListView`, then you can find your data there.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I came to ananlisar this example, only that I noticed that adapt of him is in null `.  view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem2, null);` In my case I use a players that is an array that comes from the database, only that this players is with only one item, I would like to pass two items to view.
Could you tell me where you get the data coming from the database? This is my doubt.

Comment: @RenatoLima, for first question, I don't understand what is null, check the [official demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/CustomRowView/) see what's wrong by your side. For question "I would like to pass two items to view.", you can inflate your own layout for each row, this layout can have two controls to display your item, in the `GetView` method, you can find each control in this row and set data to it. For your last question, it depends on which database you are using, besides this is not directly related to this case, ask a new question.